# Get indices of matrix from upper triangle without numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I would like to get indices for an upper triangle matrix. I am aware of np.triu_indices, but cannot use it in my application at the moment.

I can get its values from the below code, but not sure how to get its indices.

Please advice

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    print(matrix[i][i+1:]) # For excluding the main diagonal elems
```

In the above example, I would like the indices for 2, 3, and 6

Comment: What are the indices for 2, 3, and 6? Do you want the same thing `np.triu_indices` would return?

Comment: @pho - Yes, ideally same as what np.triu_indices returns. up_rows and up_cols, Should be something like an array([0, 0, 1]) for rows and array([1, 2, 2]) for the cols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the indices, you're using them to access elements in `matrix`

Instead of using them to index into `matrix`, add them to a list:

```
row_indices = []
col_indices = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    row = matrix[i]
    col_ix = list(range(i+1, len(row)))
    row_ix = [i] * len(col_ix)
    row_indices.extend(row_ix)
    col_indices.extend(col_ix)
```

Now `row_indices` and `col_indices` contain the indices you're looking for.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITveYo9ZjUIWv/BJwlBSht1oU1KGrA@fUwai@2elpn9Zqf7@Jc1RQht6R0NcAMptwJ2AgolQO4FHAQc03oScBZwUYoxZ993MjVVuk@AYpVtlsLDOiAgA640T80bbXh@gHhlECdGxMusSVKjNqakCg31nmeS1rFNwiOAiBOb7yIIq9HN6MzOZTZ68NrUPBP4/7K0J5p1joznswD8STMIQ/gC)